# SharePoint Online Share feature permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, share

I am currently fighting to understand how the permissions to create Sharing link are working on SharePoint Online.
Some library allow sharing link to be created for files but not for folders.

This is for a folder:

[image: share folder link settings]

And this is for a file:

[image]

I have look around on several settings at site and library level but found nothing...

Anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

You need to deactivate **Limited-access user permission lockdown mode** site collection feature.

Site settings -> site collection features -> deactivate **Limited-access user permission lockdown mode**

After the feature is deactivated, these options will be enabled when sharing the folder.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, this worked for persons with full access rights to the folder.

Comment: However, I would like for visitors with restricted rights to be able to also generate sharing links (Anyone type). Is that possible? What are the minimum rights needed to generate such sharing links?

Comment: Per my testing results, the user who has Contribute permission at least can share the file/folder to anyone with the link.

Comment: Hi Joanna, thanks, this seems to confirm what I tested as well.
I would like to let users be able to share to Anyone while only having read access though... seems not possible (yet?)...

Comment: no, it is impossible for users who only have read access.